# PDO query don't go to table SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I got a problem with PDO...

I have this code:

```
                        <center>
            <?php

            /*
                $payid = $_GET["payid"];
                $data = mysql_connect('localhost','cheapacc_ross2','dsaikoepwq2312','cheapacc_account');
                mysql_select_db('cheapacc_account',$data);
                $pay1 = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Categorie,Naam,Email,md5_ID FROM acount_Betalingen WHERE md5_ID = '".$payid."' ");
                $pay = mysql_fetch_object($pay1); 
                if($pay){
                    echo 'betaling is gelukt';
                }else{
                    echo 'Oops jij liegt ons voor?? '.$pay->md5_ID .mysql_error();
                }
                */

                $flag=0;
                require_once '../../include/config.php';
                require_once '../../include/processes.php';
                $Login_Process = new Login_Process;
                $Login_Process->check_status($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

                $type = base64_decode($_GET["t"]);
                $amount = (int)base64_decode($_GET["a"]);

                $host = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "20101998";
                $dbname = "ross23";

                try
                {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname, $username, $password);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    exit("Error database connection. E: " . $e);
                }

                $info = $_SESSION['info'];

                if(!isset($_GET["t"]) || !isset($_GET["a"]) || !isset($_GET["h"]) || sha1(md5($info)) != $_GET["h"])
                {
                    exit("1: FOUT! / You may not change the url, or you get a ip ban!");
                }

                if(isset($_GET["t"]) && isset($_GET["a"]) && isset($_GET["h"]) && sha1(md5($info)) == $_GET["h"])
                {
                    $q = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account_" . $type . " ");
                    $count = $q->fetchColumn();

                    if($count < $amount)
                    {
                        die("Er zijn te weinig accounts voor jouw betaling, meld dit aan de administrator!");
                    }

                    for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++)
                    {
              $flag=0;
                        $getid = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM account_".$type." WHERE used = ?");
                        $getid->execute( array('0') );
                        $pid = $getid->fetch();

                        if($pid[0] == null)
                        {
                                    exit("Er zijn geen accounts over, meld dit aan de administrator!");
                        }


                        $id = $pid[0]; 

                        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM account_" . $type . " WHERE id = ? AND used = ?");
                        $stmt->execute( array($id, '0') );
                        $result = $stmt->fetch();

                        if(!$result)
                        {
                            exit("2: FOUT! / You may not change the url, or you get a ip ban.");
                        }

                        $userinfo = $db->prepare("SELECT userid FROM cw_users WHERE info = ?");
                        $userinfo->execute( array($info) );
                        $userinfo = $userinfo->fetch();


                        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO account_lijst SET user_id = ? WHERE account = ?");
                        $sql->execute(array($userinfo[0], $result));


                        $user_id = $_SESSION['userid'] ; 
            // query
            $sql = "INSERT INTO account_lijst (user_id,soort) VALUES (:user_id,:soort)";
            $q = $db->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array(':author'=>$user_id,
                              ':title'=>$type));






                        $account_info = explode(":", $result[1]);

                        $html = "Account Username: " . $account_info[0] . "<br />";
                        $html .= "Account Password : " . $account_info[1];
                        $html .= "<br /><br />";
                        $flag = 1;
                        if ($flag==1){
                        $sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE account_" . $type . " SET used = ? WHERE ID = ?");
                         $sql->execute( array("1", $id) );



                            echo $html;
                        }

                        echo 'test';  
                    }
                }
```

The most of the part works but by INSERT INTO account_lijst

It doesn't works...

But i checked everything but i think everything is fine:S...

Can someone help me with this code please?

*EDIT SQL

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account_lijst` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `account` text NOT NULL,
      `date` text NOT NULL,
      `soort` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: usually with a set, you need an update, not an insert

Comment: Hii adam, No i got the accounts . But when i look to table accounts_lijst i dont get them and i dont get any error...

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Never underestimate failure, before success.

Comment: Thank you for you reaction Fred! i tryed this but when i do that.. my script dont work .. not only that insert but accout giving to

Comment: @Jaapie I think you need to change to `$sql->execute(array($userinfo[0], $result['account']));` you have a lot of issues here its hard to fit it in a single answer

Answer (score 0):

On your query :

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO account_lijst SET user_id = ? WHERE account = ?");
                    $sql->execute(array($userinfo[0], $result));
```

Try that instead :

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO account_lijst SET user_id = :user_id WHERE account = :account");
$sql->bindValue(':user_id', $userinfo['0']);
$sql->bindValue(':account', $result);
$sql->execute();
```

Should work perfectly if the parameters you gave are the good ones?
If you it doesn't can you please dump the parameters used into the query and the table's structure so we can debug deeper? :)

Comment: Thank you for your reaction Alex! Yeah i gona update my topic with the SQL ;)

Comment: alex all you did is switch the placeholders to named ones, what is that going to fix anything

Comment: Sometimes you see some "bugs" when you code and you resolve them you don't know how, just changing the way you do it....now i hav that plus the dumps i can help more ;)

Comment: Can you also do var_dump( $userinfo['0'] ) and var_dump( $result ) just before you do the query and give use what's into these var_dumps please ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code i guess (probably) there is an error near of this line due to the way you wrote the where clause:

```
 $userinfo = $db->prepare("SELECT userid FROM cw_users WHERE info = ?");
```

Try this instead:

```
 $userinfo = $db->prepare("SELECT userid FROM cw_users WHERE info = ' ? ' ");
```

As well in your insert you should use simple apostrophe in ordert o execute that insert:

```
   $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO account_lijst SET user_id = ? WHERE account = ?");
```

Hope it heps!!

Comment: No.. it doesn't help;( but thnx for your reaction!

Comment: I wonder if you have another table called:account_    ? if not, check it again because there is a piece of code which it makes me think you got another error: ------------------------------------------>                                         $id = $pid[0]; ------------>         $stmt =    $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM account_" . $type . " WHERE id = ? AND used = ?");

Comment: Do you wanna add me on skype? so i can show you whats the problem?   

HellChopper__1

Comment: Sorry foo i'm at work!! :( check your code deeply using interruption points using echo after every single if node. If it works as you expect it keep placing echos along the code until you find the exact error. Good Luck!!